# GRASS dependency issues in Windows QGIS (i.vi for instance)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have QGIS (2.14.3) and GRASS (7.0.4) desktop installed on Windows 7 and have successfully installed the "GRASS" plugin in QGIS (using plugin manager). However, some of the GRASS dependencies, such as `i.vi` or `vegetation index`modules, are not showing up in the QGIS Mapset section.

Next, I opened up the GRASS and noticed that the above dependency is actually available in GRASS under **imagery** > **satellite image products** > **i.vi** menu.

Is this an installation problem? Should I modify the plugin path in Windows?

Comment: To my knowledge the QGIS menu is hardcoded, hence an enhancement request is needed at https://hub.qgis.org (as an example, see https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15282)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you update to QGIS 2.16, you will have `i.vi` in the processing toolbox.

Grass 7 algorithms have been expanded from 169 to 314, so I think it is worth the update.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SAGA installed under QGIS platform, then you can use `vegetation index` tool located under `SAGA -> Imagery -Tools -> Vegetation index (slope based)`.

If you don't have SAGA installed, then you can install it following instructions in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/202073/63384) for a question on how to [Split multiple polylines by distance in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201955/split-multiple-polylines-by-distance-in-arcgis/202073#202073), and you will find rich of useful tools under SAGA .