# Dividing tunnel into segments of 100 meters using QGIS?

Tags: qgis-2

I have a csv file for pavement survey (potholes). It maps the pavement based on number of potholes in each segment divided into equal 100 meters. I am attaching a picture of it to view. How do I do this on QGIS? I tried different plugins but wasn't anywhere near to what I was looking for. RED indicates an area having 11-15 potholes, YELLOW indicates 5-6 potholes whereas GREEN points to 1-2 potholes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to divide a line into shorter segments, you can use a GRASS tool: `v.split.length - Split lines to shorter segments by length`, as you can see below:

You can find the tool from `Processing Toolbox -> GRASS GIS 7 -> v.split.length - Split lines to shorter segments by length`

If you installed QGIS as a standalone software, it may not contain GRASS. You need to use OSGeo4W to include GRASS and SAGA tool if you want. You can refer to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201955/split-multiple-polylines-by-distance-in-arcgis/202073#202073) on how to install GRASS using OSGeo4W.

[image]

You need to specify 200 m in the Maximum segment length. Please not that you need to use a CRS with unit of meter to get a correct result.

Comment: I dont even see GRASS option in plugins

Comment: I updated my answer for more information.

Comment: I m getting error "This algorithm cannot be run :-( 
It seems that GRASS GIS 7 is not correctly installed and configured in your system. Please install it before running GRASS GIS 7 algorithms."

Comment: Check this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225464/cannot-run-grass-algorithms-in-qgis-2-18-on-ubuntu-16-04. It may help.